# Getting SIGSEGV error in my concurrent Queue code

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, atomic

I am trying to write a single producer- single consumer queue. It is throwing segmentation fault. I have attached the case in main body it self with gdb output.  I am new to multi-threading hence not able to figure out why malloc will fail. Can someone please help.

compiling the code like this

```
clang++ -std=c++11 ConcurrentQueue.cpp -o test -lpthread
```

Below is my concurrent queue code. The failed case is also given in main block.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

template<typename T, uint64_t SIZE = 2048, uint64_t MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY = 40000000>
class ConcurrentQueue {
private:
    static constexpr unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
        return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
    }

    static constexpr uint64_t closestExponentOf2(uint64_t x) {
        return (1UL << ((uint64_t) (Log2(x - 1)) + 1));
    }

    static constexpr uint64_t mRingModMask = closestExponentOf2(SIZE) - 1;
    static constexpr uint64_t mSize = closestExponentOf2(SIZE);

    static const T mEmpty;

    T mMem[mSize];
    std::mutex mLock;
    uint64_t mReadPtr = 0;
    uint64_t mWritePtr = 0;

public:
    const T& pop() {
        if (!peek()) {
            return mEmpty;
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);

        if (!peek()) {
            return mEmpty;
        }

        T& ret = mMem[mReadPtr & mRingModMask];

        mReadPtr++;
        return ret;
    }

    bool peek() const {
        return (mWritePtr != mReadPtr);
    }

    uint64_t getCount() const {
        return mWritePtr > mReadPtr ? mWritePtr - mReadPtr : mReadPtr - mWritePtr;
    }

    bool busyWaitForPush() {
        uint64_t start = 0;
        while (getCount() == mSize) {
            if (start++ > MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void push(const T& pItem) {
        if (!busyWaitForPush()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Concurrent queue full cannot write to it!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        mMem[mWritePtr & mRingModMask] = pItem;
        mWritePtr++;
    }

    void push(T&& pItem) {
        if (!busyWaitForPush()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Concurrent queue full cannot write to it!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        mMem[mWritePtr & mRingModMask] = std::move(pItem);
        mWritePtr++;
    }
};

template<typename T, uint64_t SIZE, uint64_t MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY>
const T ConcurrentQueue<T, SIZE, MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY>::mEmpty = T{ };

int main(int, char**) {
    using Functor = std::function<void()>;

    ConcurrentQueue<Functor*> queue;

    std::thread consumer([ & ] {
        while (true) {
            if (queue.peek()) {
                auto task = queue.pop();
                (*task)();
                delete task;
            }
        }
    });

    std::thread producer([ & ] {
        uint64_t counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            auto taskId = counter++;
            auto newTask = new Functor([ = ] {
                std::cout << "Running task " << taskId << std::endl << std::flush;
            });
            queue.push(newTask);
        }
    });

    consumer.join();
    producer.join();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Below is gdb output

```
Reading symbols from test...done.
[New LWP 3242]
[New LWP 3240]
[New LWP 3241]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./test'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7f6500000020, bytes=bytes@entry=32) at malloc.c:3378
3378    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f6505f34700 (LWP 3242))]
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7f6500000020, bytes=bytes@entry=32) at malloc.c:3378
#1  0x00007f65067ba184 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=32) at malloc.c:2913
#2  0x00007f65070ace78 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000000004034da in main::$_1::operator() (this=0x1fc7db8) at ConcurrentQueue.cpp:108
#4  0x0000000000403475 in std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x1fc7db8)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:1530
#5  0x0000000000403445 in std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>::operator()() (this=0x1fc7db8)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/functional:1520
#6  0x0000000000403339 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()> >::_M_run() (this=0x1fc7da0)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/thread:115
#7  0x00007f65070d7c80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f65073a86ba in start_thread (arg=0x7f6505f34700) at pthread_create.c:333
#9  0x00007f650683d41d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
(gdb)
```

Comment: One question per question please. Once you have *working* code (a hard requirement) you could post review-requests at [the code review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As for possible reasons for your crash, what is `closestExponentOf2(SIZE)` returning? How large (in bytes) will your array `mMem` be?

Comment: I also recommend you build with extra warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` at least). It will turn up one problem (though unrelated to the crash itself).

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer the `-pthread` option instead of `-lpthread`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You may assume that there will be 2048 entries only for now.

Comment: I'm getting `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Concurrent queue full cannot write to it!` when running this - and then `valgrind` spits out a ton of memory leaks.

Comment: `asan` says `AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not getting std::runtime_error, but maybe consumer thread is starving too much that's why you must be getting the error. You may try increasing the side from 2048 to 4096. That might mitigate that problem but still segfault will persists.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was thinking of the same thing, but couldn't figure out where was this heap used after free, can you point me to the place?

Comment: @boxer_1 I had a quick look at it and came to the same conclusion as David Schwartz did in his answer. You need to fix all the UB:s before it becomes meaningful to dig deeper.

Comment: Why use pointer to `Functor`? The less pointers you use, the less chances of all the problems related to them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how can I remove the UBs?

Comment: @boxer_1 David describes this in his answer. You may have one thread reading a variable while another thread is modifying the same variable. That's UB.

Answer (score 3):

Your `push` function calls `busyWaitForPush` without holding the mutex. Then `busyWaitForPush` calls `getCount` which accesses `mReadPtr` without holding the mutex. This means that this thread may access `mReadPtr` while another thread is modifying it. That is undefined behavior.

Your `pop` function also calls `peek` without holding the mutex. This means it can access `mWritePtr` while another thread is modifying it. Again, undefined behavior.

Either the mutexes protect `mReadPtr` and `mWritePtr` or they don't. Don't try to split the difference.

Comment: if I make `mReadPtr` and `mWritePtr` as atomic and remove mutex from the code will that be the correct approach?

Comment: @boxer_1 Making individual variables `atomic` is only enough if you use them individually. Think about the line `return mWritePtr > mReadPtr ? mWritePtr - mReadPtr : mReadPtr - mWritePtr;` and that without a lock, the two variables are accessed 6 times and can have different values at each access.